# JGroups 'cannot find symbol'

Tags: java, compiler-errors, classpath, distributed-system, jgroups

I'm running through the tutorial from [this link](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9c20/ef696c2164208f69b1b69b30a4597280b0d5.pdf) (page 16) but when I compile the source files, I get about 30 'cannot find symbol' errors.

I have the JGroups .jar file in the directory and I'm compiling with the command: `javac -cp ".;jgroups-4.0.8.Final.jar" *.java` but to no avail.

Can anyone help me to get JGroups working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not all java files are on the same directory level and you reference any java classes in your sources from . then they won't be found. 
You would need to use something like ./**/*.java to include all java classes recuresively. 
This will even only work as long as all dependent classes are also packed within the jroups.jar file.
My suggestion is to setup a maven project where you add jgroups as dependency. In this case all subdependencies are automatically loaded.